# PHP Ignoring Required Field and Submitting Form

Tags: php, forms, validation, required, requiredfieldvalidator

I have the following form I have created in PHP, but for some reason the error validation isn't preventing the form from submitting. I am not a php developer typically and any help would be greatly appreciated. For some reason my checkboxes with multiple options are also not working, and throwing an error

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <!-- Basic Page Needs
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Submit Form</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- FONT
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <!-- CSS
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">

<script src='//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js'></script>
  <script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#PContent',
    theme: 'modern',
    height: 300,
    plugins: [
      'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
      'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
      'save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor'
    ],
    content_css: 'css/content.css',
    toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons'

  });
  </script>


  <!-- Favicon
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">


<style>
form label {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.clear {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

</head>
<body onload="myUploadFunction()">
  <!-- Primary Page Layout
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="one-half column" style="margin-top: 2%">


      <?php

 require 'xxx.php';

 $fnameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";

        // STEP 0. Are we getting form submission or should we show the form's field for filling?
         if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
           // STEP 1. Get the connection


            // STEP 2. Validate user's input

              if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
    $fnameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
  }



        $lname = $_POST['lname'];  
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];  
        $email = $_POST['email'];  
        $doservice = $_POST['doservice'];  
        $etype = $_POST['etype'];  
        $rtype = $_POST['rtype'];  
        $ptime = $_POST['ptime'];  
        $paddress = $_POST['paddress'];  
        $rtime = $_POST['rtime'];  
        $daddress = $_POST['daddress'];  
        $vtype = $_POST['vtype'];  
        $pcount = $_POST['pcount'];  
        $addetails = $_POST['addetails'];  
        $heardwhere = $_POST['heardwhere'];  


            // STEP 3. Properly encode user input for SQL


            // STEP 4. Construct the SQL query


 //INSERT 
 $sql = " INSERT INTO QuotesInfo ( fname, lname, phone, email, doservice, etype, rtype, 
 ptime, paddress, rtime, daddress, vtype, pcount, addetails, heardwhere )  
 VALUES ('".$_POST["fname"]."','".$_POST["lname"]."','".$_POST["phone"]."','
".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["doservice"]."','".$_POST["etype"]."','".$_POST["rtype"]."','".$_POST["ptime"]."','
".$_POST["paddress"]."','".$_POST["rtime"]."','".$_POST["daddress"]."','".$_POST["vtype"]."','".$_POST["pcount"]."','
".$_POST["addetails"]."','".$_POST["heardwhere"]."') "; 


            //$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $mysqli ); // procedural version
            $retval = $mysqli->query($sql);

            // STEP 5. Execute the SQL query
            if(! $retval ) {
                // STEP 5.1 Deal with insuccess
               die('Could not enter data: ' . $mysqli->error);
            }

            // STEP 5.2 Deal with success
            echo "Entered data successfully\n";

$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact mail";
$from=$_POST["email"];
$msg= $fname . " " . $lname . "\r\n" . $phone . "\r\n" . $email . "\r\n" . $doservice . "\r\n" . $etype . "\r\n" . $rtype . "\r\n" . $ptime . "\r\n" . $paddress . "\r\n" . $rtime . "\r\n" . $daddress . "\r\n" . $vtype . "\r\n" . $pcount . "\r\n" . $addetails . "\r\n" . implode(",  ", $heardwhere);
$headers = "From: $from";

mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
echo "Email successfully sent.";







            // STEP 6. We're done, close the connection
            //mysqli_close($mysqli);
            $mysqli->close();
         }else {
            ?>


<form id="form1" name="form1"  method = "post" action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<label for="fname">First Name</label><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
 <span class="error">* <?php echo $fnameErr;?></span>
<br class="clear" /> 
<label for="lname">Last Name</label><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" />
<br class="clear" /> 
<label for="phone">Phone</label><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
<br class="clear" /> 
<label for="email">Email</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
<br class="clear" /> 
<label for="doservice">Date of Service</label><input type="text" name="doservice" id="doservice" />
<br class="clear" /> 
<label for="etype">Event type</label><select name="etype" id="etype">
<option value="Wedding">Wedding</option>
<option value="Quinceanera/Cotillion">Quinceanera/Cotillion</option>
<option value="Corporate/Business">Corporate/Business</option>
<option value="Homecoming/Prom/School Dance">Homecoming/Prom/School Dance</option>
<option value="Bachelor/Bachelorette">Bachelor/Bachelorette</option>
<option value="Concert">Concert</option>
<option value="Sporting Event">Sporting Event</option>
<option value="Birthday">Birthday</option>
<option value="Sweet 16">Sweet 16</option>
<option value="Night Out">Night Out</option>
</select>
<br class="clear" /> 
<label for="rtype">Rental type</label><select name="rtype" id="rtype">
<option value="Hourly Rental">Hourly Rental</option>
<option value="Round Trip">Round Trip</option>
<option value="One Way">One Way</option>
<option value="Shuttle Service">Shuttle Service</option>
</select>
<br class="clear" /> 
<label for="ptime">Pickup Time</label><input type="text" name="ptime" id="ptime" />
<br class="clear" /> 
<label for="paddress">Pick Up Address and City</label><input type="text" name="paddress" id="paddress" />
<br class="clear" /> 
<label for="rtime">Return Time</label><input type="text" name="rtime" id="rtime" />
<br class="clear" /> 
<label for="daddress">Drop Off Address, City</label><input type="text" name="daddress" id="daddress" />
<br class="clear" /> 
<label for="vtype">Type of Vehicle</label><select name="vtype" id="vtype">
<option value="10 passenger limousine">10 passenger limousine</option>
<option value="22 Passenger SUV">22 Passenger SUV</option>
<option value="22-30 Passenger Party Bus">22-30 Passenger Party Bus</option>
<option value="31 Passenger Shuttle Bus">31 Passenger Shuttle Bus</option>
</select>
<br class="clear" /> 
<label for="pcount">How many passengers</label><input type="text" name="pcount" id="pcount" />
<br class="clear" /> 
<label for="addetails">Additional Details</label><textarea name="addetails" id="addetails" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
<br class="clear" /> 
<label for="heardwhere">How did you hear about us</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="heardwhere[]" value="Facebook" id="heardwhere_0" />Facebook
<input type="checkbox" name="heardwhere[]" value="Twitter" id="heardwhere_1" />Twitter
<input type="checkbox" name="heardwhere[]" value="Google" id="heardwhere_2" />Google
<input type="checkbox" name="heardwhere[]" value="Referral" id="heardwhere_3" />Referral
<input type="checkbox" name="heardwhere[]" value="Website Ad" id="heardwhere_4" />Website Ad
<input type="checkbox" name="heardwhere[]" value="Flyer" id="heardwhere_5" />Flyer
<input type="checkbox" name="heardwhere[]" value="Bridal Show" id="heardwhere_6" />Bridal Show
<input type="checkbox" name="heardwhere[]" value="Quinceanera Show" id="heardwhere_7" />Quinceanera Show
<input type="checkbox" name="heardwhere[]" value="Yelp" id="heardwhere_8" />Yelp
<input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Save">
<br class="clear" /> 
</form></div>



<div class="one-half column" style="margin-top: 2%">

<?php


$sqli = "SELECT fname, lname, phone, email, doservice, etype, rtype, ptime, paddress, rtime, daddress, vtype, pcount, addetails, heardwhere FROM QuotesInfo "; 

$resulti = $mysqli->query($sqli);

if ($resulti->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $resulti->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "" . $row["fname"]. " " . $row["lname"]. " : " . $row["phone"]. "<br>"
. $row["email"]. " " . $row["doservice"]. " : " . $row["etype"]. "<br>"
. $row["rtype"]. " " . $row["ptime"]. " : " . $row["paddress"]. "<br>"
. $row["rtime"]. " " . $row["daddress"]. " : " . $row["vtype"]. "<br>"
. $row["pcount"]. " " . $row["addetails"]. " : " . $row["heardwhere"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}



?>

</div>



     <?php
         }

         function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
      ?>




    </div>
  </div>
<!-- End Document
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your validating the input to some extent, but in your if/else statements you need to do some kind of escape if the values aren't set, probably using:
    If(!isset($value)){
        Errors[] = 'value not set';
    }

```
If(isset($errors)){
    Echo your error handling
} else {
    The rest of your script
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. You are using "$errors", which I have made no mention of in my example script. Thus, I don't understand where I would add this new code block. Are you suggesting I replace  "if(isset($_POST['add']))"?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use exit() function after your if condition like this

```
 if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
    $fnameErr = "Name is required";
    exit();
}
```

Now this will first checks your fname, if it is empty it will exit

Comment: No, still submits the form.

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing you have to do is just put all your php code in one Block. I don't know what you are doing, you start a if condition in your first block and end that in another block.
2. Use If else Condition correctly. I checked your code and found that you started a if condition and then start else condition but after that you start another else condition. Ok use if else condition correctly.
3. I have changed your code when some variables are posted in your file. Check this this will surely solved your problem. 
   I have successfully run this code on my system.

   ```
    <?php
   ```

   $fnameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";

   ```
       // STEP 0. Are we getting form submission or should we show the form's field for filling?
   ```

   //if fname is posted 
            if(isset($_POST['fname'])) {
              // STEP 1. Get the connection

   ```
           // STEP 2. Validate user's input

             if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
   $fnameErr = "Name is required";
   ```

   } else { //else condtion and remember all your if else condition should be
             // in this block only not out of this
       $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
       $lname = $_POST['lname'];
           $phone = $_POST['phone'];
           $email = $_POST['email'];
           $doservice = $_POST['doservice'];
           $etype = $_POST['etype'];
           $rtype = $_POST['rtype'];
           $ptime = $_POST['ptime'];
           $paddress = $_POST['paddress'];
           $rtime = $_POST['rtime'];
           $daddress = $_POST['daddress'];
           $vtype = $_POST['vtype'];
           $pcount = $_POST['pcount'];
           $addetails = $_POST['addetails'];
           $heardwhere = $_POST['heardwhere'];

   ```
           // STEP 3. Properly encode user input for SQL


           // STEP 4. Construct the SQL query
   ```

   //INSERT 
    $sql = " INSERT INTO QuotesInfo ( fname, lname, phone, email, doservice, etype, rtype, 
    ptime, paddress, rtime, daddress, vtype, pcount, addetails, heardwhere )
    VALUES ('".$_POST["fname"]."','".$_POST["lname"]."','".$_POST["phone"]."','
   ".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["doservice"]."','".$_POST["etype"]."','".$_POST["rtype"]."','".$_POST["ptime"]."','
   ".$_POST["paddress"]."','".$_POST["rtime"]."','".$_POST["daddress"]."','".$_POST["vtype"]."','".$_POST["pcount"]."','
   ".$_POST["addetails"]."','".$_POST["heardwhere"]."') ";

   ```
           //$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $mysqli ); // procedural version
           $retval = $mysqli->query($sql);

           // STEP 5. Execute the SQL query
           if(! $retval ) {
               // STEP 5.1 Deal with insuccess
              die('Could not enter data: ' . $mysqli->error);
           }

           // STEP 5.2 Deal with success
           echo "Entered data successfully\n";
   ```

   $to = "myemail@gmail.com";
   $subject = "Contact mail";
   $from=$_POST["email"];
   $msg= $fname . " " . $lname . "\r\n" . $phone . "\r\n" . $email . "\r\n" . $doservice . "\r\n" . $etype . "\r\n" . $rtype . "\r\n" . $ptime . "\r\n" . $paddress . "\r\n" . $rtime . "\r\n" . $daddress . "\r\n" . $vtype . "\r\n" . $pcount . "\r\n" . $addetails . "\r\n" . implode(",  ", $heardwhere);
   $headers = "From: $from";

   mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
   echo "Email successfully sent.";

   ```
           // STEP 6. We're done, close the connection
           //mysqli_close($mysqli);
           $mysqli->close();
        }
      // this is your else condition, make sure it will be also in else 
     //condition above. I have commented this coz I have no database :P
        //else {
            $sqli = "SELECT fname, lname, phone, email, doservice, etype, rtype, ptime, paddress, rtime, daddress, vtype, pcount, addetails, heardwhere FROM QuotesInfo ";
   ```

   $resulti = mysqli_query($con, $sqli);

   if ($resulti->num_rows > 0) {
       // output data of each row
       while($row = $resulti->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo "" . $row["fname"]. " " . $row["lname"]. " : " . $row["phone"]. "
   "
   . $row["email"]. " " . $row["doservice"]. " : " . $row["etype"]. "
   "
   . $row["rtype"]. " " . $row["ptime"]. " : " . $row["paddress"]. "
   "
   . $row["rtime"]. " " . $row["daddress"]. " : " . $row["vtype"]. "
   "
   . $row["pcount"]. " " . $row["addetails"]. " : " . $row["heardwhere"]. "
   ";
       }
   } else {
       echo "0 results";
   }
          }

   ```
        function test_input($data) {
   ```

   $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
   }

   ```
           ?>
   ```

Check out this code and try to understand it. Hope this will work now. Happy Coding :)